# autoloader issue in phpexcel with Magento 1.4.2.0

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

We have getting these warning in PHPExcel in Magento.
Checked path, permissions and others things seems all good.

Seems some autoloader issue is there.
2016-09-30T20:55:24+00:00 ERR (3): 192.168.56.1 - Warning: include(PHPExcel/Shared/ZipStreamWrapper.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 68
2016-09-30T20:55:24+00:00 ERR (3): 192.168.56.1 - Warning: include(): Failed opening 'PHPExcel/Shared/ZipStreamWrapper.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/public_html/app/code/local:/home/public_html/app/code/community:/home/public_html/app/code/core:/home/public_html/lib:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')  in /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 68

2016-09-30T20:55:24+00:00 ERR (3): 192.168.56.1 - Warning: include(PHPExcel/Shared/String.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2016-09-30T20:55:24+00:00 ERR (3): 192.168.56.1 - Warning: include(): Failed opening 'PHPExcel/Shared/String.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/public_html/app/code/local:/home/public_html/app/code/community:/home/public_html/app/code/core:/home/public_html/lib:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')  in /home/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93

Comment: You might find some inspiration here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: thanks for the comments, but seems that its related to autoloader conflicting (Magento Default one and the phpexcel lib)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?